# Is there a detailed comparison between Propel 2 and Doctrine 2

Tags: performance, orm, doctrine, comparison, propel

From the existing comparisons between 1.x versions of Propel and Doctrine, I couldn't decide whether to use Doctrine 2.x or Propel 2.x for my new project. I have some experience with Propel but am not happy with the way Propel 2 broke compatibility with previous versions. Hence this question. Is Doctrine 2 worth the switch from Propel 2?

Comment: Surely Propel 1 to Doctrine 2 will break compatibility more than Propel 1 to Propel 2? (I personally think it's too early to move to Propel 2 anyway - the API is not stable yet).

Comment: (I think this question should be closed anyway - it's largely a matter of opinion, and it has attracted two link-only answers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also during making my decision which PHP ORM to choose and recently I found the following comparison of the main features of Doctrine2 and Propel 2:
[Side by side: Doctrine2 and Propel 2](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/side-by-side-doctrine2-and-propel-2-comparison).
The comparison is very precise and comprehensive, so surely it can come in handy when making the decision.

Answer (score 0):

They're the only resources I could find on it. There are some useful comparisons.

I'm not used Doctrine, but finding my way around Propel 2 at the moment and so far I like it.

- http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/2x41ey/doctrine_2_vs_propel_2/
- http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1qime6/propel_vs_doctrine/

Comment: Hi there. Would you be so kind as to summarise the essence of those two links in your answer? We try to discourage link-only (or predominantly link-only) answers since they're subject to breakage (in this case, Reddit users may delete their posts).